Как через батник открыть ссылку в браузере хром?
Есть ответ на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352463/writing-a-batch-file-that-opens-a-chrome-url#comment69606013_24594649.
Но он не рабочий, так как если запустить файл cmd с start chrome https://www.google.co.in/ то запускается консоль бесконечное количество раз, как описано тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352463/writing-a-batch-file-that-opens-a-chrome-url#comment69606013_24594649
При этот если запустить start chrome https://www.google.co.in/ в консоле напрямую, не используя бат файл, то корректно открывает ссылку в браузере.
Как исправить, чтобы открывало ссылку и через батник?

@像插頭一樣愚蠢 Вы через bat файл запускаете? У меня windows 10

С обоими форматами файла отрабатывает одинаково неверно у меня

Да, в описании же указано, что start chrome https://www.google.co.in/ отрабатывает в консоли, очевидно что хром стоит

запускается консоль бесконечное количество раз - это как? не верю.  хотя... вы случайно не назвали свой bat-файл chrome.bat ?  )))  Поздравляю, вы создали форк-бомбу )))

Форк бомбу можно оформлять в ответ, работает, спасибо

Ну так chrome это не файл, напишите
start chrome.exe https://www.google.co.in/

Батник, ввиду дубовости, распознает файл хром не как программу, а как файл без разрешения.
